# How to get value from command line using for loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Following is the code for extracting input from command line into bash script:

```
input=(*);
for i in {1..5..1}
do
    input[i]=$($i);
done;
```

My question is: how to get $1, $2, $3, $4 values from input command line, where command line code input is:

```
bash script.sh "abc.txt" "|" "20" "yyyy-MM-dd"
```

Note: **Not using** for i in "${@}"

Comment: What is wrong with `for i in "$@"; do...`? Do you just not like it?

Comment: You can simply write `for i; do...`, without adding `in "$@"`. I think this is the most natural way to traverse over the input parameters.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

for ((i=$#-1;i>=0;i--)); do 
  echo "${BASH_ARGV[$i]}"
done
```

Example: `./script.sh a "foo bar" c`

Output:

```
a
foo bar
c
```

Comment: In bash script we can extract input value using '$1', '$2' etc... so how can we extract that values using for loop, where 1, 2 values are coming pragmatically.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correctly understanding what you're trying to do, you can write:

```
input=("$@")
```

to copy the positional parameters into an array named `input`.

If you specifically want only the first five positional parameters, you can write:

```
input=("${@:1:5}")
```

---

**Edited to add:** Or are you asking, given a variable `i` that contains the integer `2`, how you can get `$2`? If that's your question, then — you can use *indirect expansion*, where Bash retrieves the value of a variable, then uses that value as the name of the variable to substitute. Indirect expansion uses the `!` character:

```
i=2
input[i]="${!i}"     # same as input[2]="$2"
```

This is almost always a bad idea, though. You should rethink what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you have against `for i in "$@"; do...`, but you can certainly do it with `shift`, for example:

```
while [ -n "$1" ]; do
    printf " '%s'\n" "$1"
    shift
done
```

**Output**

```
$ bash script.sh "abc.txt" "|" "20" "yyyy-MM-dd"
 'abc.txt'
 '|'
 '20'
 'yyyy-MM-dd'
```

Personally, I don't see why you exclude `for i in "$@"; do ...` it is a valid way to iterate though the args that will preserve quoted whitespace. You can also use the array and C-style for loop as indicated in the other answers.

**note:** if you are going to use your `input` array, you should use `input=("$@")` instead of `input=($*)`. Using the latter will not preserve quoted whitespace in your positional parameters. e.g.

```
input=("$@")
for ((i = 0; i < ${#input[@]}; i++)); do
    printf " '%s'\n" "${input[i]}"
done
```

works fine, but if you use `input=($*)` with arguments line `"a b"`, it will treat those as two separate arguments.